# How to compose a zero-argument function?

Tags: scala, function-composition

What I want to achieve is the 2 functions (one of them is no arg function) are composed into one.

Here is an example to give you idea what I am doing:

```scala
object Test extends App {

  val zeroArgFunc = () => 10
  val intArgFunc = (i: Int) => s"hello $i"
  val stringArgFunc = (s: String) => println(s)

  // This line works perfectly fine.
  val intAndThenString: Int => Unit = stringArgFunc compose intArgFunc

  // But this line fails with 'type mismatch' compilation error.
  val zeroAndThenInt: () => String = intArgFunc compose zeroArgFunc

}
```

Compilation error:

```
[error]  found   : () => Int
[error]  required: ? => Int
[error]   val zeroAndThenInt: () => String = intArgFunc compose zeroArgFunc
[error]                                                         ^
[error] one error found
```

Any idea what's wrong?

[UPD] The Scala version is 2.13.1  (if it matters).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Desugaring `() => 10` we have

```
new Function0[Int] { def apply() = 10 }
```

and [`Function0`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/049417ee2a0671f06488f755b3a9c7dc6a048dfa/src/library/scala/Function0.scala#L35) does not have `compose` or `andThen` methods

```
trait Function0[... +R] extends ... { ...
  def apply(): R
  override def toString(): String = "<function0>"
}
```

so it seems `Function0` cannot be composed.

On the other hand `(i: Int) => s"hello $i"` and `(s: String) => println(s)` correspond to [`Function1`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/049417ee2a0671f06488f755b3a9c7dc6a048dfa/src/library/scala/Function1.scala#L65) which does have `compose` method defined, hence they can be composed.

Consider changing `() => 10` to `(_: Unit) => 10` which changes the type from `Function0` to `Function1`, and then

```
(intArgFunc compose zeroArgFunc)()
```

outputs `res4: String = hello 10`.

---

Addressing comment by @Duelist, IMHO `Function0[T]` is not semantically equivalent to `Function1[Unit, T]`. For example, given

```
val f = () => 10
val g = (_: Unit) => 10
```

then

```
f()
g()
```

indeed outputs

```
res7: Int = 10
res8: Int = 10
```

however

```
f(println("woohoo")) // error: no arguments allowed for nullary method apply                                                             
g(println("woohoo")) // OK!
```

where we see the two do not have the same behaviour. Nevertheless, if you would like to consider them as equivalent perhaps you could define an extension method on `Function0` and be explicit about conversion, for example

```
implicit class Fun0ToFun1[A, B](f: () => A) {
  def toFun1: Unit => A = (_: Unit) => f()
}
```

would allow the following syntax

```
(intArgFunc compose zeroArgFunc.toFun1)()
```

---

Addressing comment by @egordoe, out-of-the-box `compose` is only ever defined for `Function1`, thus `Function2`, `Function3`, etc., [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44181481/5205022) be composed just like `Function0`. However we could define extension `composeN` methods on function, for example, say we want to compose `Function1` with `Function0`, then

```
implicit class ComposeFun1WithFun0[A, B](f1: A => B) {
  def compose0(f2: () => A): () => B = () => f1(f2())
}
```

gives

```
(intArgFunc compose0 zeroArgFunc)()
```

Comment: That's interesting. Why `Function0[T]` can't be considered as `Function1[Unit, T]`?

Comment: @Duelist See [Functions without arguments, with unit as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2774788/5205022)

Comment: @MarioGalic @Duelist Looking at this from the opposite side, why would both `Function0` and `Function1` not have 2 overloaded versions of the compose method - `def compose(g: A => T1)` and `def compose(g: () => T1)`?

Answer (score 1):

`compose` on `Function1` (which `intArgFunc` is) is just [defined](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html#compose[A](g:A=%3ET1):A=%3ER) to only accept single-argument functions:

```
def compose[A](g: (A) => T1): (A) => R
```

You could write helper functions to convert `() => A` to/from `Unit => A`

```
def toUnitFun[A](f: () => A): Unit => A = _ => f()
def fromUnitFun[A](f: Unit => A): () => A = () => f(())
```

and then

```
val zeroAndThenInt = fromUnitFun(intArgFunc compose toUnitFun(zeroArgFunc))
```

You can even make your original code work by marking `to/fromUnitFun` as `implicit`.